# Monotouch iOS - PerformSegue from function

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm working through Monotouch/Xamarin examples and trying to stitch together a storyboard segue and a Windows Azure Mobile Services (WAMS) authentication. I have each working independently but I just can't seem to trigger a segue after a valid WAMS login. No error is thrown in the DoLogin() function and the AlertView works. It just seems to skip over the PerformSegue. The PerformSegue in ViewDidLoad() works fine.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();    

        btn_Facebook.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Facebook clicked");
            DoLogin(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
        };

        btn_Twitter.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Twitter clicked");
            this.PerformSegue("seg_Login", this);
            // DoLogin(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter);
        };
}

private void DoLogin(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider)
    {
        string applicationKey = "[removed]";
        string applicationUrl = "https://[removed].azure-mobile.net/";

        MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationUrl, applicationKey);

        var task = client.LoginAsync(this, provider).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
           MobileServiceUser user = t.Result;

           this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
           {
               this.PerformSegue("seg_Login", this);

               UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Logged In!", string.Format("Hello user {0}", user.UserId), null, "OK");
               alert.Show();
           });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had a support engineer at Xamarin stumped too and it's been submitted as a bug. However, I found a very simple addition to get this working. By adding a timer and creating a half second delay, I was finally able to trigger the segue.

```
this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Timer tm = new Timer(new TimerCallback((state) =>
                {
                    this.InvokeOnMainThread(new NSAction(() =>
                    {
                        this.PerformSegue("seg_Login", this);
                    }));
                }), null, 500, Timeout.Infinite);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the current implementation class implement prepareforseque or are you literally pushing it all to the storyboard. 
I would suggest implementing prepareforseque and put a break point in there to see if its getting that far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to simply push it all to the storyboard with a PerformSegue which seems to work fine in ViewDidLoad. I took your advice and implemented a PrepareForSegue with a break point. It is hitting the break point but the segue never fires.